# Create different range arrays from one big one

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have an array that contains other arrays of US colleges broken down by the first letter of the alphabet. I've setup a test page so that you can see the array using print_r. That page is:

http://apps.richardmethod.com/Prehealth/Newpublic/test.php

In order to create that array, I used the following code:

```
    $alphabetized = array();

    foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {

            // create new array based on letter
            $alphabetized[$letter] = array();

            // loop through results and add to array
            foreach ( $users as $user ) {
                    $firstletter = substr($user->Schoolname, 0, 1);

                    if ( $letter == $firstletter ) {
                        array_unshift( $alphabetized[$letter], $user );
                    }
            }
    }
```

Now, I want to split the array so that a certain range of letters is in each array. For example,

arrayABCEFGH - would contain the schools that begin with the letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H.

My question is, should I modify the code above so that I achieve this before I do one big array, OR should I do it after?

And here is the big question . . if so, how? :-)

Thanks in advance for any help. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the code to generate the array can be made easier by only iteratating over `$users`:

```
$alphabetized = array();

// loop through results and add to array
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $firstletter = strtoupper($user->Schoolname[0]);

    $alphabetized[$firstletter][] = $user;
}
// sort by first letter (optional)
ksort($alphabetized);
```

To retrieve the first 8 entries you could use `array_slice`:

```
array_slice($alphabetized, 0, 8);
```

Assuming that all first letters are actually used and you used `ksort()` on the full array that also gives you from A - H. Otherwise you have to use `array_intersect_key()` and the flipped range of letters you wish to query on.

```
array_intersect_key($alphabetized, array_flip(range('A', 'H')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple function that takes an array, and an array of keys to extract from that array, and returns an array containing just those keys and their values.  A sort of `array_slice` for non-numeric keys:

```
function values_at($array, $keys) {
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
}
```

Which you can then call like this to get what you want out of your alphabetized list:

```
$arrayABCDEFGH = values_at($alphabetized, range('A','H'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a full copy of the array, then you should encapsulate the above code in a function that has an array as its argument ($letterRange), which will hold the specific array identifiers (letters) to be in the final array.

Then you would need to encapsulate the code within the foreach using an if block:

`if (in_array($letter, $letterRange)) { ... }`

This would result in an array only containing the letter arrays for the specified letters in $letterRange.